# How to create Eloquent model with relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

How to create Eloquent model with relationship?

I have:

**Person table**

```
id
firstname
lastname
```

**Employee table**

```
id
person_id
position
```

I want to do something like this:

```
Employee::create([
'firstname' => 'Jack',
'lastname' => 'London',
'position' => 'writer'
])
```

I know, that can create two model and then associate their. But may be there is a way do this more beautiful?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First, you have to create relation in your Person model

```
class Person extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['firstname', 'lastname'];

    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Employee');
    }
}
```

After that in your controller you can do:

```
$person = Person::create($personData);
$person->employee()->create($employeeData);
```

As [@Alexey Mezenin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1227923/alexey-mezenin) mentioned you can use:

```
$person = Person::create(request()->all());
$person->employee()->create(request()->all());
```

Also inverse would be:

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['position'];

    public function person()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Person');
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to separate data source (I.e. `$request->all()`), it will work without separation because of mass assignment.

Comment: I updated my question to make it more clear, thank you for mention this...

Comment: Cool. Also you can't say "if you're using mass assignment", because `create()` method always uses mass assignment.

Comment: Yes you are right so I added $fillable fields into model

Comment: What if `person.employee_id` is not nullable and `person` table have another not nullable relation column, for example `person.wallet_id`?
Is there another way than add `employee_id` and `wallet_id` to `$fillable` and set it manually in that case?

Comment: I'm really wary of things like mass assignment and protected fields as when you define them in the model you then have no idea what functions you have that will fill those fields. This means that if you then discover that a particular field is not right to be in the mass assignments field list you can't remove it without knowing that the effect is. Personally, I would go with a specific method on the model instead, e.g. public function createNewEmployee($firstName, $lastName ... etc). It's then super clear what it does and super easy to change if you need to.

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting "column cannot be null". The guarded array is empty, so I don't know why that relation and its idea aren't added to the create array automatically. I have `this->hasMany(Question::class, "topic_id")// on the topic model`, and it says topic_id cannot be null

Answer (score 11):

You still need to create person first, so if you're looking for readable and consize solution, you can do is this:

```
$data = [
    'firstname' => 'Jack',
    'lastname' => 'London',
    'position' => 'writer'
];

$person = Person::create($data);
$person->employee()->create($data);
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting "column cannot be null". The guarded array is empty, so I don't know why that relation and its idea aren't added to the create array automatically. I have `this->hasMany(Question::class, "topic_id")// on the topic model`, and it says topic_id cannot be null

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you create a static method that creates the instance and related models. Many times you not only create a model, but you may have to populate it with some additional data and having a single `createModel()` method is a best practice.

In my case:

```
public static function createCompany($data) : Company {
    $company = new Company($data);
    $company->save();
    $company->settings()->create();
    // TODO Configure settings according to $data

    $company->blog()->create();
    // TODO: Create demo blog post

    // TODO: Create default admin user.
    // TODO: Etc.
}
```

All these details can be abstracted from the controller, in which I only call:

`$company = Company::createCompany($request->all());`

Comment: What about transaction? I'd wrap that operations into transaction.