# Insert parent and child at once in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, insert

I am trying to insert data at once in my both `users` and `user_details` table. See below code:

**Model:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function user_detail() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserDetail', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : ''}}">
    {!! Form::label('username', 'Username:* ', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {!! Form::text('username', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required']) !!}
        {!! $errors->first('username', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>
...
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('user_detail[about_me]') ? ' has-error' : ''}}">
    {!! Form::label('user_detail[about_me]', 'About Me: ', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-md-6">
        {!! Form::textarea('user_detail[about_me]', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required' => 'required']) !!}
        {!! $errors->first('user_detail[about_me]', '<p class="help-block">:message</p>') !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $data = $request->except('password'); //dd($data);
    $user = User::create($data);
    $user->user_detail->create($data['user_detail']);
}
```

**Error Message:**

[image]

In above I have posted my code(Removed rest fields. Keep only user table `username` and user_details `about_me`)

In my above code data inserted successfully in the `users` table but error occur while inserting in the child table.

Please look my code and suggest me how to insert  record in my child table.

Comment: Possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509900/how-to-create-eloquent-model-with-relationship

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong code is `$user->user_detail`. It must be `null` or instance of `UserDetail`, because you now created user `$user->user_detail` it must be `null`. You must be use `$user->user_detail()` instead of `$user->user_detail` . Corrected code is

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
    $data = $request->except('password');
    $user = User::create($data);
    if ($user) {
        $user->user_detail()->create($data['user_detail']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also you must be be sure `$data['user_detail']` is array