# General error: 1364 Field 'products_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, migration

Hello I've two tables :

products :

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('title');
            ...
            $table->boolean('slider_mode')->default(false);
        });
    }
```

and slider :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('slider', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            ...
            $table->integer('products_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('products_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Problem is when I'm creating products table with slider, product's id is not referencing in `products_id`

Here is my controller ( store function) :

```
...
 if($x1['slider_mode'] == 1){      # x1 is $request->all();
            Slider::create($x1);
        }
        Product::create($x1);


        return redirect('admin/products');
```

should `products_id` is not be completed automatically with product's id when I create both ?

but I'm getting error:

> General error: 1364 Field 'products_id' doesn't have a default value

Comment: why don't simply make product_id nullable , if you're not storing it will creating slider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set up relations inside your models,
You can do that like this:

```
$product = Product::create($x);
$product->sliders()->create($x);
```

A newly created slider will automatically have a `product_id` of product.

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509900/how-to-create-eloquent-model-with-relationship) I think that's it what you need.

Answer (score -1):

`product_id` is auto-increment but for `products` table not for the `slider` table.

If you want to insert into the `slider` table without `product_id`, you must update the `products` table migration and set the value to be nullable:

```
$table->integer('products_id')->unsigned()->index()->nullable();
```

Or if you want `product_id` also you should set the `product_id`.